# Using Multiple input windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create multiple input windows, but when I finish answering the questions, I get an error.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
window2 = False


#--------ACTION 2-----------

def action2():
    window2 = False
    global e4
    Address = e4.get()
    print("The address is", Address)
    global e5
    ConsDate = e5.get()
    print("The date of construction is", ConsDate)
    global e6
    LastRemoDate = e6.get()
    print("The date of the last remodel is", LastRemoDate)


#----------SECOND WINDOW---------

def window2():
    window2 = tkinter.Tk() 
    window2.title("Name Software")

    TitleLabel = ttk.Label(window2, text = "Name Information")
    TitleLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    L4 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is your address?")
    L4.grid(row =1, column = 0)

    e4 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e4.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    L5 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is the original date of construction?")
    L5.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    e5 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e5.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    L6 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is the date of the last remodel?")
    L6.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    e6 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e6.grid(row = 3, column = 1)


    btn = ttk.Button(window2, text = "Submit Answers", command = action2)
    btn.grid(row = 5, column = 1)



window2()
```

When I run this, it gives me the error

```
Line 12, in action2
Address = e4.get()
NameError: name 'e4' is not defined
```

How do I fix this? I copied it from my other part of the script and changed the questions. The first part works, but this doesn't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should change the title of this question. The question has nothing to do with multiple windows.

Comment: It did have multiple windows, I just shortened the code to show the part that wasn't working.

Comment: your _program_ may have multiple windows, but the _question_ isn't at all about multiple windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `global e4,e5,e6` to the top of the `windows2()` function so that in the function you are using a global variable (which 'action2()' is accessing) rather than using local which it is currently using.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
window2 = False

#----------SECOND WINDOW---------

def window2():
    window2 = tkinter.Tk() 
    window2.title("Name Software")

    global e4,e5,e6

    TitleLabel = ttk.Label(window2, text = "Name Information")
    TitleLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    L4 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is your address?")
    L4.grid(row =1, column = 0)

    e4 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e4.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    L5 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is the original date of construction?")
    L5.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    e5 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e5.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    L6 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is the date of the last remodel?")
    L6.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    e6 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e6.grid(row = 3, column = 1)


    btn = ttk.Button(window2, text = "Submit Answers", command = action2)
    btn.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

#--------ACTION 2-----------

def action2():
    window2 = False
    global e4
    Address = e4.get()
    print("The address is", Address)
    global e5
    ConsDate = e5.get()
    print("The date of construction is", ConsDate)
    global e6
    LastRemoDate = e6.get()
    print("The date of the last remodel is", LastRemoDate)

window2()
```

Comment: That didn't work. It just changed the error to         line 41, in action2.                                        Address = e4.get()                                  NameError: name 'e4' is not defined

Comment: Yep sorry, didn't read the code well enough. Edited my answer to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the variables global in both functions. Try:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
window2 = False
#global e4,e5,e6
#----------SECOND WINDOW---------

def window2():
    global e4,e5,e6
    window2 = tkinter.Tk() 
    window2.title("Name Software")

    TitleLabel = ttk.Label(window2, text = "Name Information")
    TitleLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    L4 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is your address?")
    L4.grid(row =1, column = 0)

    e4 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e4.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    L5 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is the original date of construction?")
    L5.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    e5 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e5.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    L6 = ttk.Label(window2, text = "What is the date of the last remodel?")
    L6.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    e6 = ttk.Entry(window2, width = 50)
    e6.grid(row = 3, column = 1)


    btn = ttk.Button(window2, text = "Submit Answers", command = action2)
    btn.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

#--------ACTION 2-----------

def action2():
    global e4,e5,e6
    window2 = False
    Address = e4.get()
    print("The address is", Address)
    ConsDate = e5.get()
    print("The date of construction is", ConsDate)
    LastRemoDate = e6.get()
    print("The date of the last remodel is", LastRemoDate)

window2()
```